# Minification is breaking my AngularJs code

Tags: angularjs, minify, cassette

I'm using Cassette which uses the Microsoft Ajax Minifier to minify JS. This minifier renames variables, including variables that have special meaning to Angular, such as `$scope` and `$http`. So Cassette breaks my Angular code!

How can I prevent this happening?

For reference, this is the Angular code which is being broken. The `$scope` and `$http` function parameters are being renamed:

```
// <reference path="vendor/angular.js" />

angular.module('account-module', [])
    .controller('ForgottenPasswordController', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.email = {
            value: '',
            isValid: false,
            containerStyle: "unvalidated",
            validate: function () {
                var valid = isEmailAdressValid($scope.email.value);
                $scope.email.isValid = valid;
                $scope.email.containerStyle = valid ? "valid" : "invalid";
                return valid;
            },
            removeErrorMessage: function() {
                $scope.email.containerStyle = "unvalidated";
            }
        };

        $scope.display = {
            formClass: '',
            congratulationsClass: 'hide'
        };

        $scope.submit = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var emailValid = $scope.email.validate();
            if (emailValid) {
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/account/forgot-password',
                    params: { email: $scope.email.value },
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
                }).success(function(data) {
                    $scope.success(data);
                }).error(function() { $scope.error(); });
            }
        };

        $scope.success = function (data) {
            switch (data.Outcome) {
                case 1:
                    $scope.display.formClass = "hide";
                    $scope.display.congratulationsClass = "";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $scope.email.containerStyle = "invalid";
                    break; 
            }
        };

        $scope.error = function () {
            alert('Sorry, an error occurred.');
        };

        function isEmailAdressValid(emailAddress) {
            return /[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+/.test(emailAddress);
        }
    });
```

Comment: could you show your controller syntax to us then we can comment if you are using right syntax or wrong syntax

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To prevent code minifiers from destroying your angular application, you have to use the array syntax to define controllers.

Look at http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/13/angularjs-controllers-dependencies-and-minification.aspx

(From OP):
For reference, here is the changed code:

```
angular.module('account-module', [])
    .controller('ForgottenPasswordController', ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {
...
}]);
```

Comment: I don't mean to overdramatise, but you have saved my life and the future of all humanity.

Comment: I would agree, I had no idea it was so simple. I'm trying to support a legacy application and none of the files are minified so for me this was absolute gold! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure when Cassette Added this, but when you create a bundle you can use `AddMinified` to indicate that the file is as minified as it can be without breaking it (It won't be minified when it's served).

That being said, it's much better to use angular's array syntax because smaller files are better!

Comment: Thanks for a potentially useful alternative.